# pip version mismatch in venv

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

I am confused about how virtual Python environments work (Python 3.6, using `venv`). I set up my venv, and activated it in the command line. I would expect that everything I do from then on out uses the python and pip commands from the virtual environment (as these directories are added to PATH upon activation).

The thing is, that when I run `pip --version` in my `venv`, it returns `pip 10.0.1`. But when I try to upgrade it with `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`, I get `Requirement already up-to-date`

```
(venv) PS C:\Python\files\myproj> pip --version
> pip 10.0.1 from c:\python\files\myproj\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-10.0.1-py3.6.egg\pip (python 3.6)
(venv) PS C:\Python\files\myproj> python -m pip install --upgrade pip
> Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\python\files\myproj\venv\lib\site-packages (18.0)
```

So what's going on? Why isn't the command line command targeting the same `pip` as `python` is? And how to remedy this?

Comment: You `pip` command points to an other pip version than the one in your venv. `python -m pip` uses the version in your venv.

Comment: So when in an active `venv`, the pip version is the global one? And only the global `python` is swapped for the venv's python?

Comment: Your PATH variable does not seem to be set up properly.

Comment: Can you expand on that?

Comment: pip `10.0.1` should be uninstalled by the `update`, how about `pip list`, `pip uninstall pip 10.0.1` in youe venv, and update again

Comment: @KlausD. BUT why then when I use `pip install a-package` in an activated environment, the package is installed in the environment and not globally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pip` still points to the global one, even when in an venv. `python`, however, does not and uses the venv.

This means that when you run `pip --version`, you get your global pip version. when you run `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`, you're using the venv version of python, which apparently already has the newest pip. To confirm this, you can run `python -m pip --version` and you should get the latest version as an output.

Comment: BUT why then when I use `pip install a-package` in an activated environment, the package is installed in the environment and not globally?

Comment: hey, @BramVanroy, why did you unaccept my answer? what you asked in the comments is another question.

Comment: At least in my setup, this is not what happens. `$ python3 -m pip --version
pip 19.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
$ source env/bin/activate
$ python3 -m pip --version
pip 19.2.3 from /Users/mtopol/python/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)`